# Why did Netflix cancel the OA after season 2?

Tags: cancellation, the-oa

Netflix has canceled the OA after its second season, in spite of the show's hardcore fanbase. What is the reason behind this?

Answer (score 2):

According [to this](https://www.wired.com/2019/08/geeks-guide-the-oa/):

> Unfortunately for the show’s small but devoted fanbase, Netflix
>   recently canceled The OA after two seasons. Science fiction writer
>   Anthony Ha was disappointed but not surprised, given recent trends at
>   Netflix.
>
> “They had a really bad quarterly earnings report, and subscriber
>   growth is not going the way they want it to, so they had a number of
>   cancellations around the same time,” he says.

Answer (score 2):

According to Jason Isaacs, the actor who played Dr. Hunter Aloysius Percy AKA "Hap":

> “I was crushed [when The OA was cancelled],” he told **RadioTimes.com**. “It's one of the odd things that happen in the new media world that you're cancelled not because of numbers, but because of other corporate needs.
>
> "Netflix needs to build subscribers and they make their decisions on a bunch of other things, which are not to do with the number of people watching, more to do with how many people they can get to sign up.”
>
> He added: “I know the Netflix execs who made the decision to cancel it felt equally sad because they had five seasons mapped out and the show has this rabid committed fanbase. Those people felt very upset. I wouldn't want to be sitting in the Netflix executive chairs!”

- [*Jason Isaacs says The OA wasn’t cancelled due to poor viewing figures*. RadioTimes.com](https://www.radiotimes.com/tv/sci-fi/jason-isaacs-oa-cancellation-ratings/)

Comment: So reading between the lines, the execs felt they had already cornered the "sci-fi mystery" market, and those subscribers could be taken for granted and would never go away, so they'd get more return on investment chasing different, less saturated audiences?  I feel like that attitude didn't age well